# How do I select a single cell in a WPF datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selection, cell

When I click a cell in a WPF datagrid, the whole row is selected, and when I press Ctrl + C to copy the content, the whole row i copied...

How do I select and copy the content of a single cell?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use SelectionUnit Property of Datagrid. For example:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell;
```

Where unit can be Cell, CellOrRowHeader or FullRow.

Comment: does it make sense to set selectionMode to single when you set SelectionUnit to cell?

Answer (score 3):

WPF datagrid comes up with the 'SelectionUnit' property. 
You can set the following values 'SingleCell/FullRow/CellorRowHeader'. 
If you want to select multiple rows, use the 'SelectionMode' property and set the value to 'Extended.'

Answer (score 0):

This is an option in the WPF grid, you should have a property named SelectionMode (or something like that depending of the datagrid you're using) that define how cells are selected.

Comment: SelectionMode is for how many of the specified SelectionUnit can be selected.

Comment: I think it's actually a helpful bit of information to be associated with this question.  I recently needed both (which is why I found this question).